# Connect multiple application with one mongo database using Mongoose (ORM)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongo database with mongoose (ORM). I have a database that is working well with Express framework Application. Now I want to connect to this database with another Express Application. 
Now here is the question,
should I make all mongoose models again in new project with Mongoose ? if not then what will be best option for this that we can use still use existing database mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not serving the data via a REST API then.  If you create a REST API for the mongoose models and then serve that data through URL's you won't have to create new models, rather you could just request the data via HTTP through GET, POST, DELETE, etc requests from the new express application.

If you want me to elaborate further, I can certainty do so.